# How to evacuate large parties of people from urban areas into safe zones within a reasonable amount of time?

Tags: natural-disasters

Let's say there's a virus or a tsunami or a tornado in a mega city (similar to [Coruscant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coruscant) city from Star Wars). The event takes place in the middle of the day, so the streets are packed.

How could I funnel large crowds through streets into safe zones that are located 2 miles away, with minimal casualties and as quickly and efficiently as possible also note that this takes place in the middle of the day when the streets are extremely crowded with traffic,people, ect. they would be trying to get away from a tsunami or tornado.

Comment: Hello. I think your question is rather broad, because you're not telling us much about the situation. What sort of setting is this taking place in? Manhattan Island? A small European town? What are they running away from? Is this taking place during a major event when the streets are packed with people and vehicles? Or is it taking place in the middle of the night, when everyone is asleep? All of these factors significantly affect the answer. Polish up your question and provide more details, please.

Comment: Here's some good reading regarding the scope of questions on WB SE: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3206/worldbuilding-scope-risk-factors?cb=1

Comment: 2 miles of streets for large crowds, takes lots of discipline, the kind one gets raised with, and drills drills drills. When I was wearing the uniform we got taught that crowds are often worse than the disaster they run away from. And with a random undisciplined crowd the word "funnel" spells disaster. There are computer simulations used for evacuation buildings, subway systems etc and those are complicated enough for a much smaller scale than yours. Evacuating Tokyo? good luck...

Comment: oh yeah AndreiROM sorry about that cant beileve i forgot about it this takes place in a very very large city kinda like coruscant from star wars  the event is taking place in the middle of the day when the streets are packed and the scenario is like a tsunami or tornado.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include that information. Comments are temporary and may be deleted at any time for any reason.

Comment: Read "A Torrent Of Faces" by James Blish. In the story there are trillions of people living on Earth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the number of people in the crowd and the breadth of the streets they are moving through. In the scenario you outlined the crowd would be moving in a panic and so any kind of orderly conduct is out of the question.

In a coruscant like city, the best way to move a large crowd quickly would be to send them down a street or passage bigger than the crowd, at least enough so that each individual has enough room to maneuver around others/casualties.

[image]

Whether they would reach the safe zone in time depends how fast the tornado is moving, how much of a head start they have, whether they are walking or running, as well as how big the entrance to the safe zone is. If the entrance to the safe zone is small there will be a large backlog as people fight their way in. Studies have shown that putting a pole or other thin obstacle in front of a narrow entrance can speed up a panicked crowd, since people need to alternate to get in. The average jogging speed is 10min per mile, and allowing for constant dodging around casualties and other obstacles it would probably take 30-40 minutes for a fit person in the crowd to be in the safe zone. If you add injured people, out of shape people, young, and old, then you would probably need a 2-3 hour head start from the disaster front.

Comment: The question is very poorly framed, and the OP hasn't really clarified the key points needed to answer it. However, even going on the little that _is_ provided, you're not really answering the question: **How could i funnel large crowds through streets"** Telling us that we should get people to use broad streets is a moot point - we knew that. The OP's questions is _how do you get them to do that_. And you can't really answer, because it depends on a lot of different variables which the OP isn't providing. So the best course of action is not to (answer) play the game.

Comment: A good read: [Should we answer off-topic questions?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3120/should-we-answer-off-topic-questions/3121#312)

Comment: Also a good read: [Is WB a what-if site?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/is-worldbuilding-a-what-if-site?rq=1)